# Subquery - SQL Registros específicos

Tags: sql

Preciso extrair minha base toda para um arquivo csv (ano 2022), porém existem registros de uma coluna especifica(BASE) que eu só posso trazer o mês 12 referente a ele.

tentei dessa forma:

select * from bdpo
where ano = 2022
    (select BASE  from base_perdas_operacionais 
    where BASE in ('C','T','TR') and mes = 12
)
OBS: Obviamente ele trouxe os valores duplicados do mês 12

| ANO | MES | VALOR | BASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 12 | 5 | C |
| 2022 | 12 | 6 | T |
| 2022 | 11 | 22 | C |
| 2022 | 11 | 6 | T |
| 2022 | 1 | 7 | TR |
| 2022 | 1 | 10 | J |
| 2022 | 5 | 15 | TR |

Comment: Faltam detalhes para opinar , estrutura e relacionamento das tabelas , se possível faça um exemplo no sqlfiddle, informe também a tag do SGBD em questão.

Comment: O TAINMAT conseguiu uma opção de resultado que deu certo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tenta igual abaixo.

SELECT
ANO
,MES
,VALOR
,BASE
FROM bdpo
WHERE ANO = 2022 AND BASE NOT IN('C','T','TR')

UNION ALL

SELECT
ANO
,MES
,VALOR
,BASE
FROM bdpo
WHERE ANO = 2022 AND MES = 12 AND BASE IN('C','T','TR')

Comment: deu certo! era isso mesmo que eu precisava